java.io.InvalidClassException: Filtering rejected org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractUnmarshaller$FilterInputImpl
Is this really the impact of the jar 'jboss-marshalling 2.0.11', do I need to update the jar ? will it solve the problem of marshalling?
Tech stack:

Java 11.x
JBoss 7.4.x

Which jar is compatible with the existing version of JBoss and Java 11?
I have checked the project structure and found out that in JBoss server, we have jar "jboss-client.jar" which contains jboss-marshalling jar having version 2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001 and on the client side we have version 2.0.11.Final for both jboss-marshalling and jboss-marshalling-river.I have updated the client library to 2.0.14 to match with server jar compatibility but still I am getting the same exception.
stack trace:
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.io.InvalidClassException: Filtering rejected org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractUnmarshaller$FilterInputImpl@770e574f: unmarshallClass=<class java.math.BigInteger> arrayLength=<-1> depth=<7> references=<300001> streamBytes=<2495409> 
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.15.GA-redhat-00002//org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.AssociationImpl.receiveInvocationRequest(AssociationImpl.java:151)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.53.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.EJBServerChannel$ReceiverImpl.handleInvocationRequest(EJBServerChannel.java:477)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.53.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.EJBServerChannel$ReceiverImpl.handleMessage(EJBServerChannel.java:212)
    at org.jboss.remoting@5.0.27.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel.lambda$handleMessageData$3(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:432)
    at org.jboss.remoting@5.0.27.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(EndpointImpl.java:993)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.11.SP1-redhat-00001//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.EJBClientChannel$MethodInvocation$ExceptionResultProducer.getResult(EJBClientChannel.java:1433)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:620)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:551)
    at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:622)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:551)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.java:148)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:622)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:551)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:622)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:551)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.NamingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(NamingEJBClientInterceptor.java:87)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:622)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:551)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.call(AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:622)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:551)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionInterceptor.java:212)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:622)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:551)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.awaitResponse(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:1003)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:182)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.updateConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Suppressed: org.jboss.ejb.client.RequestSendFailedException: org.jboss.remoting3.remote.OutboundMessage$1@12dc7dea: remote side closed the message stream @ remote+https://fub-ppega1.caas-p07.telekom.de:443
        at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.EJBClientChannel.processInvocation(EJBClientChannel.java:492)
        at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemoteEJBReceiver$1.lambda$handleDone$0(RemoteEJBReceiver.java:95)
        at org.xnio.FinishedIoFuture.addNotifier(FinishedIoFuture.java:79)
        at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemoteEJBReceiver$1.handleDone(RemoteEJBReceiver.java:80)
        at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemoteEJBReceiver$1.handleDone(RemoteEJBReceiver.java:78)
        at org.xnio.IoFuture$HandlingNotifier.notify(IoFuture.java:208)
        at org.xnio.AbstractIoFuture$NotifierRunnable.run(AbstractIoFuture.java:856)
        at org.xnio.IoUtils$2.execute(IoUtils.java:71)
        at org.xnio.AbstractIoFuture.runNotifier(AbstractIoFuture.java:829)
        at org.xnio.AbstractIoFuture$CompleteState.withNotifier(AbstractIoFuture.java:267)
        at org.xnio.AbstractIoFuture.addNotifier(AbstractIoFuture.java:706)
        at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemoteEJBReceiver.processInvocation(RemoteEJBReceiver.java:142)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:499)
        at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocation(RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:514)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.java:82)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:514)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocation(DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.java:116)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:514)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.NamingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocation(NamingEJBClientInterceptor.java:69)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:514)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.lambda$handleInvocation$0(AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.call(AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocation(AuthenticationContextEJBClientInterceptor.java:44)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:514)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:205)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:514)
        at org.wildfly.common.context.Contextual.runExConsumer(Contextual.java:203)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequestInitial(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:341)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:178)
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: org.xnio.BrokenPipeException: org.jboss.remoting3.remote.OutboundMessage$1@12dc7dea: remote side closed the message stream
        at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.OutboundMessage$1.accept(OutboundMessage.java:121)
        at org.xnio.streams.BufferPipeOutputStream.send(BufferPipeOutputStream.java:122)
        at org.xnio.streams.BufferPipeOutputStream.send(BufferPipeOutputStream.java:110)
        at org.xnio.streams.BufferPipeOutputStream.getBuffer(BufferPipeOutputStream.java:74)
        at org.xnio.streams.BufferPipeOutputStream.write(BufferPipeOutputStream.java:92)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.OutboundMessage.write(OutboundMessage.java:300)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.AbstractDelegatingMessageOutputStream.write(AbstractDelegatingMessageOutputStream.java:105)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.OutputStreamByteOutput.write(OutputStreamByteOutput.java:52)
        at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.NoFlushByteOutput.write(NoFlushByteOutput.java:34)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.SimpleDataOutput.shallowFlush(SimpleDataOutput.java:353)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.writeKnownObject(RiverMarshaller.java:435)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:217)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1182)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1140)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.writeKnownObject(RiverMarshaller.java:742)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:217)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1182)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1140)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.writeKnownObject(RiverMarshaller.java:771)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:217)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1182)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1140)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
        at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.EJBClientChannel.processInvocation(EJBClientChannel.java:398)
        ... 72 more
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: Filtering rejected org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractUnmarshaller$FilterInputImpl@770e574f: unmarshallClass=<class java.math.BigInteger> arrayLength=<-1> depth=<7> references=<300001> streamBytes=<2495409> 
    at org.jboss.marshalling@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractUnmarshaller.filterCheck(AbstractUnmarshaller.java:122)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1563)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:441)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:373)
    at org.jboss.marshalling@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectInputStream.readFields(RiverObjectInputStream.java:156)
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.readObject(BigDecimal.java:4239)
    at org.jboss.marshalling@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callReadObject(JDKSpecific.java:148)
    at org.jboss.marshalling@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callReadObject(SerializableClass.java:252)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1997)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1601)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:441)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:388)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:2107)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:2020)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1601)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:441)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:388)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadCollectionObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:344)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readCollectionData(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1055)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:908)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:388)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:2107)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:2020)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1601)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:441)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:388)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadCollectionObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:344)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readCollectionData(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1055)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:939)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:388)
    at org.jboss.marshalling@2.0.14.SP1-redhat-00001//org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.53.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.EJBServerChannel$RemotingInvocationRequest.getRequestContent(EJBServerChannel.java:845)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.15.GA-redhat-00002//org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.AssociationImpl.receiveInvocationRequest(AssociationImpl.java:149)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.53.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.EJBServerChannel$ReceiverImpl.handleInvocationRequest(EJBServerChannel.java:477)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.53.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.EJBServerChannel$ReceiverImpl.handleMessage(EJBServerChannel.java:212)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.11.SP1-redhat-00001//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)


I'm not really sure what you're asking. That said, this looks like JBoss EAP 7.4, if you have support I'd contact the support team. It's not real clear to me what you're attempting to do here.
